# Salesforce Products Customization

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

I'm curious if anyone has found a reliable solution with using SF Products in the following scenario.

Our business model does not have a standard Term or Amount for our products.  For example, Product A has a 3 month term with a total budget of $5K.  However, months 1 & 2 are $2K while the 3rd month is $1K.

When setting up a product, there is Qty & list price but doesn't allow the breakdown if monthly spend is different.

One note - Product Schedules wouldn't solve this with the current workflow.

Comment: Can you use a custom object? Can make a related list

Comment: Thanks!  I'd prefer not to use a Custom Object since Products funnel to our quotes & ERP system.

Comment: It's great that they funnel into your pipeline but it sounds like you need something that it doesn't support. That is your call. Generally, something that has multiple parts requires a one-to-many relationship and I can't imagine you'll find a way to get around that physical limitation. Note: you can make rollups to track a total budget of some custom object with a master-detail relationship. Alternately, you can have a process that calls a flow that sums multiple related records and saves the total on the product "price". You would not need a master-detail in that scenario

Answer (score 0):

With CPQ we can have block pricing and configure units as months and calculate the pricing but for that customer needs to have the CPQ package and license.

If the customer doesn't have a CPQ package then the customer needs to have customer implementation of their own to support the tiers.

With a custom solution, you can reinvent the wheel that CPQ has provided.

Thanks!